# How to use 'sysdate' if its a string constant

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I extract data from a table, the field is mostly null, but sometimes it's sysdate. However since its from a table, after getting the field its `'sysdate'`, between single quotes. How can I use it?

I have tried to_date, to_date(to_char()).
I need something that works within

```
 select to_date('sysdate') from dual;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case expression:

```
select case 
          when the_column = 'sysdate' then sysdate
          else to_date(the_column)
       end as date_value
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is **dynamic SQL**. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, col varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 1, '''sysdate''' from dual union all
  3    select 2, null          from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_res test%rowtype;
  3    l_str varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select id, col from test) loop
  6      l_str := 'select ' || cur_r.id ||', '||
  7                  nvl(replace(cur_r.col, chr(39), null), 'null') || ' from dual';
  8      execute immediate l_str into l_res;
  9      dbms_output.put_line(l_res.id ||': '|| l_res.col);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
1: 24.06.2019 12:18:39
2:

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```